# Should "crossed" really be there as an equivalent of this definition?

Tags: word-usage

I read a definition of the word "squint" in [Merriam Webster Dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squint) which was:

> of the eyes : not having the visual axes parallel : CROSSED

"Crossed" (or cross-eyed) is in fact a **type** of a pathological condition relating to eye known as Strabismus or squint-eyed. So I don't think it should really be there as the equivalent of the definition because it is a **type** of the squint-eyed disease which is broader term and the type is specific.

Comment: It is not "crossed": it is cross-eyed. It is not a disease, it is a condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cross-eyed" may not be medically accurate, but it is a common term for the alignment of the eyes where both look are turned inwards.  It doesn't have to be a medical condition; most people can consciously "cross" and "uncross" their eyes at will.

[image]

Also, medically speaking, "cross-eyed" is only one possible alignment of *strabismus*.

> Squint, also called strabismus, is an eye condition where the eyes do not look in the same direction as each other. This means that while one eye looks forwards to focus on an object, the other eye turns either inwards, outwards, upwards or downwards.

Comment: @Andrew- No offense, I knew almost everything you said in your answer. That's not what I asked. I wanted to know whether "crossed" should really be there as an equivalent of "squint" because it is in fact a type of the condition(squint)  not the condition itself (which I think is in fact the case but think myself as too immature to find a mistake in a dictionary). I'd be very obliged if you consider that and reply at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: @kelvin  The dictionary has numerous references to "crossed" as a synonym of "squint", which you can find in other sources, e.g. https://www.aoa.org/patients-and-public/eye-and-vision-problems/glossary-of-eye-and-vision-conditions/strabismus .  If this still doesn't help then I'm afraid I don't understand your concern.  There may be some debate among professionals whether "crossed" should be used in a medical context, but that's outside the scope of ELL, which deals with common English usage.